# Where can I get the Mishnah Torah in English in plain text, open source?

Tags: product-recommendation, rambam, mishneh-torah

I want to upload and maintain various texts in English in plain text format for wikisource: https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Portal:Judaism
In particular, I am looking for the Mishnah Torah in English. It needs to be freely re-printable and not copy right protected. Please help me with those so Jewish text can be more widely accessible. Any other plain text documents are also welcomed.

Comment: https://mechon-mamre.org/i/0.htm

Comment: @kouty Mechon-Mamre claims copyright protection.

Comment: There's already a MT on Hebrew Wikisource [here](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%9C%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9D). This is the primary one used on Sefaria, and its licence is CC-BY-SA.

Comment: Maybe http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/d_root__035_rambam.html - unsure about their license.

Comment: It is in Hebrew, I can only read in English.

Comment: @NoahQ'yain Please check that my edit matches your intent.

Comment: There is an English translation here https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/682956/jewish/Mishneh-Torah-Rambam.htm by R. Eliyahu Touger https://www.gefenpublishing.com/authorcategory.asp?id=2093, but according to the following page it looks like it's copyrighted so you would have to inquire - https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/130435/jewish/Privacy-Policy-and-Terms-of-Service.htm

Answer (score 0):

On the website [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/texts/Halakhah/Mishneh%20Torah), one can find the entirety of *Mishneh Torah* by Moses Maimonides. In every chapter that I have spot-checked at random, they display both a Hebrew text and an English translation. It states that the translation is that of Phillip Birnbaum from 1967. Hopefully this will meet your requirements for learning from this book.

Comment: It’s actually a very patchy translation. Most halachot aren’t translated on Sefaria.

Comment: @Zarka That's because Birnbaum's _Mishneh Torah_ was an abridged translation.

Comment: Yup. And it therefore doesn’t fulfil the OP’s needs (in several ways)

Comment: I need to learn Hebrew. It sucks Hebrew is hard to content with the fact that Hebrew is such a holy language.

Comment: Is this the same Birnbaum that compiled a very excellent high-holidays machzor?

Comment: @MarkFischler  yes, and a classic siddur, one of the first English translations to be accepted by Orthodox communities. Apparently *Mishneh Torah* was translated in a rather different style.